# How can I send a message to a specific client connected through socket

Tags: php, sockets

Hello This is my first time working on sockets. I have multiple clients which connect to my socket server through a specific port. I want to send a specific message to a specific client. how can I do that?.

I am using this [library](https://github.com/navarr/Sockets)

https://github.com/navarr/Sockets

This is the code

```
<?php

use Navarr\Socket\Socket;
use Navarr\Socket\Server;

class EchoServer extends Server
{
    const DEFAULT_PORT = 7;

    public function __construct($ip = null, $port = self::DEFAULT_PORT)
    {
        parent::__construct($ip, $port);
        $this->addHook(Server::HOOK_CONNECT, array($this, 'onConnect'));
        $this->addHook(Server::HOOK_INPUT, array($this, 'onInput'));
        $this->addHook(Server::HOOK_DISCONNECT, array($this, 'onDisconnect'));
        $this->run();
    }

    public function onConnect(Server $server, Socket $client, $message)
    {
        echo 'Connection Established',"\n";
    }

    public function onInput(Server $server, Socket $client, $message)
    {
        echo 'Received "',$message,'"',"\n";
        $client->write($message, strlen($message));
    }

    public function onDisconnect(Server $server, Socket $client, $message)
    {
        echo 'Disconnection',"\n";
    }
}

$server = new EchoServer('0.0.0.0');
```

This line  `$client->write($message, strlen($message));` will send a message to a client if only one client is connected. but if multiple clients connected then how can I send a message to specific client?

Comment: You need to track users in `session`? And then send them respective feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code inside onConnect function.

```
//declare this as global inside EchoServer class so that you can access this outside onConnect function
$connected_clients["userID"] = $client; //use unique id for key
```

Then to send message, use the `userID` to access right client:

```
$connected_clients["userID"]->write($message, strlen($message));
```

To get `userID`, once the client connect to your server request for the client id, example: use JSON for easy communication, send this JSON message

```
{"messageType":"request", "requestType": "identification"}
```

to client. On client side process the message and send this JSON message

```
{"messageType":"response", 
 "body":{"userID":"123456", "accessToken":"ye5473rgfygf737trfeyg3rt764e"}}
```

back to server. On the server side validate the access token and retrieve `userID` from the response. `userID` is unique identification number store in database which is assign to each user during there registration to your chat site.

To know the client that send message, use this JSON message format

```
{"messageType":"message", 
 "from":"userID", 
 "body":"message here"}
```

Modify to suit your preference.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. I have one question. How can I know that this client is the one I am looking for and send data to this specific client. what I meant is that in OnConnect function I am receiving resource id. but how can I identify the user.

Comment: do the client has to send something from his end which I have to get in the onconnect function ?

Comment: or the other way around is I will ask one client to send some specific string for example "helloworld" and in onInput function I will check helloworld string. but then how can I indentify which user has send me the hello world text so I send him the response according to it

Comment: i have edited the answer to reflect your knew question

Comment: Thank you very much. If I have any other question can I ask you here again about the same topinc?

Comment: Hello I am having a problem in socket. could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50659538/connection-reset-by-peer-php-socket?noredirect=1#comment88330181_50659538